# Force network location to "Work network" in Windows 7 Home edition

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-firewall

I have a Windows 7 Home computer that I have disabled the "Set Network Location" popup on with this registry hack:

```
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network\NetworkLocationWizard\
Name: HideWizard (DWORD)
Value: 1
```

And now I would like all future network connection to be forced to "Work network".

I need a black box with a server app that has to run on any network it is connected to, which requires the network to be trusted in order for firewall rules to allows traffic to my server app.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that you can only set network policies to Private or Public, but there isn't much difference between Private and Work. A Private network is trusted.

Open the Local Security Policy Editor (Start->Run "secpol.msc" ).
Under Security Settings, select "Network List Manager Policies" and then select
a network name from the displayed names (I don't know exactly which name will apply in your case).
Right-click and select Properties and set the "Location type" to Private.
Reboot.

Comment: Thats exactly what i need. The only problem is that i'm using Windows 7 Home, which does not feature the Local Security Policy Editor. Is it possible to tweak via the registry?

Comment: See if this helps : http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/itprovistanetworking/thread/66b42761-1b8e-4302-9134-0bb685139f4e