# Force Windows 7 to treat all networks as 'Work'

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking

I would like to know if it is possible to have Windows 7 (Home Premium) set to treat all new network connections as 'Work Network'?

The default behaviour is that a window pops up and asks you which type of network you want to assign to it (Home, Work or Public). There is an option to treat all as public, but I have found no way to force Windows to treat all networks as 'Work'.

I'd appreciate any feedback as to how to make any new connection a 'Work Network' and not have the popup come up each time.

Is this possible?

Comment: For security it's probably not achievable...

Comment: Why would you want do this? This can expose your machine (and your privacy) significantly? There may be better ways if you tell us what your underlying problem is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force network location to "Work network" in Windows 7 Home edition](http://superuser.com/questions/72573/force-network-location-to-work-network-in-windows-7-home-edition)

Comment: I have a machine that is taken to various locations and each time the user has to go through this and I would like to stop it. I understand the security implications, but the device is connected to a trusted network, I just do not want to have to do this each time. Thank you

Comment: This article may help you out with the prompts: http://serverfault.com/questions/634982/how-to-avoid-the-prompt-do-you-want-to-find-pcs-devices-and-content